# how to make my recaptcha required before login the person in

Tags: php, html

So I was not sure on how to make it so that you have to also do recaptcha before you are able to be logged in, if anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            

                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="The description on my site">
        <meta name="keywords" content="some keywords ill add when i have my site">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device.width, user.scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA Compatible" content="ie-edge">
        <title>MYsitename | Login</title>


        <!--Logo for tab-->

        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="64x64" href="images/bwlogo.ico">

        <!--Ion Icons-->

        <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--jQuery CDN-->

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!--Google Fonts-->

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aldrich&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--Cookie-warning-->

        <script src="js/cookie-warning.js"></script>

        <!--Our own stylesheet-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">

        <!--Script for recaptcha-->

        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="inside-wrapper">
        <div class="anchor-tag-style"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/bwlogo2.png" class="logo-above-text"></a></div>
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p class="please-fill-message">Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <br>
                <span class="help-block" style="color: red;"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                <br>
                <span class="help-block" style="color: red;"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mysitekeybutiobviouslywontshowheheh"></div>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Sign up now</a>.</p>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cookieConsent">
            This website is using cookies. <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie" target="_blank">More info</a>.<a class="cookieConsentOK">That's Fine</a>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

So there you have it, so again, the problem is I don't know how to make it so that you have to go to recaptcha so that you are able to login or else it will show an error message just like the other ones i made in the  and in the php code and it won't let you login until you do it.

Comment: Did you try something ? The documentation that might help is here https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: @challet ill try that, thx